# Show $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} \frac {|x_1x_2-y_2x_1 - y_1x_2 +y_1y_2)|} {||(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)||} = 0$ in order to show $f$ is differentiable.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow t} \frac {||f(x)-f(y)-L(x-y)||} {||x-y||} =\lim_{x \rightarrow y} \frac {|x_1x_2-y_1y_2-y_2(x_1-y_1) - y_1(x_2-y_2)|} {||(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)||}  = \lim_{x \rightarrow y} \frac {|x_1x_2-y_1y_2-y_2x_1 +y_2y_1 - y_1x_2 +y_1y_2)|} {||(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)||}  =  \lim_{x \rightarrow y} \frac {|x_1x_2-y_2x_1 - y_1x_2 +y_1y_2)|} {||(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)||} = 0 $$

to prove that $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^1$ given by $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$ is differentiable.

I've computed the partial derivatives as $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_1} = x_2$ and $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_2} = x_1$, so the linear transformation is given as $L(x) = y_2x_1 +y_1x_2$ at the point $y=(y_1,y_2)$.

Now I want to verify that the limit above is actually $0$. I've heard that $f$ should be differentiable if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous, but I want to verify it manually !

Can someone help to verify the limit above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|x_1x_2-y_2x_1-y_1x_2+y_1y_2|=|(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)|$$
Now $||(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)||=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}\geq \sqrt{(x_2-y_2)^2}=|x_2-y_2|$.

Hence for $(x_1,y_1)\neq (x_2,y_2)$:
$$\frac{|x_1x_2-y_2x_1-y_1x_2+y_1y_2|}{||(x_1,x_2)-(y_
1,y_2)||}\leq \frac{|(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)|}{|x_2-y_2|}=|x_1-y_1|$$
Now clearly:
$$\lim_{x\to y} |x_1-y_1|=0$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{x\to y,\;x\neq y}\frac{|x_1x_2-y_2x_1-y_1x_2+y_1y_2|}{||(x_1,x_2)-(y_
1,y_2)||}=0 $$